# How to avoid sprinkling chowns all over

Tags: docker

I'm trying to figure out how it's supposed to work based on these two articles:

https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b

https://vsupalov.com/docker-shared-permissions/

I am setting up a dockerfile based on an image that has user Ubuntu already set (the subject of the first linked article above) so that the container runs by default under user `ubuntu`. This is adhering to best practice.

The problem I'm having is that the code directories `COPY`ed in the dockerfile are all owned by root, and calling `cmake ..` required for the docker build fails because of this. I understand that the COPYs will by default run as root, and that even if I use the --chown flag with COPY, any parent directories implicitly created by the COPY would be owned by root regardless of any --chown flag used.

- Doesn't the fact that the container already has a Ubuntu user mean that calling `RUN adduser --uid 1000 ubuntu` in the dockerfile (the suggestion from the second linked article above) would be problematic (it'd be at best redundant)?
- Then that would mean that we would not want to `RUN adduser` so does this mean the only remaining option is to actually just sprinkle tons of chowns everywhere in the dockerfile? I refuse to do this.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the edit, but https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235051/12497 indicates usernames are actually case sensitive, I wouldn't necessarily consider it proper to refer to the ubuntu user with a capital U since that's not its actual name.  It is just that it is named after the name of the distro, which has the capital U, but the username itself has a lowercase u. My pedantry is more intense than yours! Take that!

Comment: Do you actually need to `chown` anything at all?  Can you run the build process as root, leave the installed files owned by root, and switch to `USER ubuntu` only at the very end of the file when specifying the default `CMD`?

Comment: Maybe but when I tried it there were numerous permissions related issues. It almost seemed like prior to specifying `USER ubuntu` that only some things were being run as root. Which I agree is quite strange. I will dig into it more the next time I encounter this.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `USER ubuntu` near the top of the dockerfile prior to any of the COPYs it appears to work to eliminate most of the required `sudo chown` calls. There will still be some required, if some part of the directory tree being copied to started out owned by root and need to be owrked with later.